# Передача файла из Dropzone.js в бэкенд .NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Код на стороне бэкенда

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(IFormFile files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("POST OK " + files.FileName);

    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        Console.WriteLine(filePath.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("FILENAME " + files.FileName);
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\dm" + files.FileName))
        {
            await files.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Код на стороне фронта  - плагин Dropzone.js, перетаскиваешь туда файл и он его отправляет на /upload-files

Я сделал роут `upload-files` и метод `OnPostUploadAsync(IFormFile files)` успешно вызывается, о чем свидетельствует срабатывание `Console.WriteLine("POST OK " + files.FileName);`

К сожалению срабатывает он нульрефом и говорит что `IFormFile files` равен null

Вопрос - в каком формате передает Dropzone.js? Какой формат аргумента подставить?

В официальной документации написано

Dropzone не предоставляет реализацию обработки файлов на стороне сервера, но способ загрузки файлов идентичен простым формам загрузки файлов:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Тогда какие аргументы мне нужно написать на стороне сервера?

Comment: вы же можете поставить точку останову и посмотреть содержимое HttpRequest ?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код на стороне бэкенда по сути правильный, за исключением одного нюанса.

Название аргумента `OnPostUploadAsync(IFormFile files)` должно соответствовать названию передаваемого параметра.

В вашем случае название аргумента указано как `files`, а dropzone.js по умолчанию использует `paramName: "file"`

Чтобы решить проблему вы либо меняете имя аргумента в бэкенде:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {
    Console.WriteLine("POST OK " + file.FileName);

    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        Console.WriteLine(filePath.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("FILENAME " + file.FileName);
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\dm" + file.FileName))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Либо меняете имя параметра dropzone в JS:

```
Dropzone.options.myForm = {
    paramName: "files"
};
```

Где `myForm` - id вашей html формы:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-form">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: Третий способ, для полноты картины - `[FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile files`.